# Safari browser crashes, when unfocus and focus again tab with jquery code website

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari, crash, webkit

I create simple image slider, using *jQuery*. Tested on all browers. All works fine, but not in WinXP Safari. When i open another tab and load other website, and then focus again on my jQuery slider website tab - Safari crashes. Its happend only when my slider website actually animate images using *fadeIn* effect. When i try to switch tabs on my site, Safari crashes. I find what causes that, but not find an solution to the problem. Problem is probably with window resize and functions defines of dimensions of images and DIVs. And/or maybe *setInterval* function. I find many websites with different javascript and jQuery scripts with the same problem and no solutions (i.e. http://www.jssor.com/demos/banner-slider.html).

Comment: You should *probably* look up Safari bugtracker https://bugreport.apple.com/

Answer (score 0):

I find solution. Problem disappeared when i start script from:

```
$(window).focusout(function() {
   if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Safari") > -1) {
     location.reload();
     }
});
```

I hope, that will help in some other problems with Safari.